# On a PV cell, why do electrons travel through the copper rather than through the PN junction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

thank you all for reading me!

I am currently reviewing the structure and working principles of a PV cell. I think I understand the following steps about how the PN junction is formed and what happens when light hits it:

- There is a chemical potential which makes electrons to diffuse from the N region to the P region
- This diffusion creates an electrostatic potential which causes electrons to go the opposite way
- When both potentials are matched, both currents are equal, so no net flow takes place
- When light hits the depletion zone, an electron is excited to the conduction band and goes to the N region due to the electrostatic potential. The hole does the opposite

Please correct me if my understanding is not right, but, based on this I don't understand the following step: when the excited electron goes into the N region, it cannot go into the P region through the depletion zone because there is a potential difference between the two zones. But apparently it can go through the copper to the rear connection of the P region. Wouldn't the potential difference be the same no matter which way the electron travels? Why is the electron able to travel through the copper connection?

Comment: If you short circuit the cell, yes, weird things happen. Now insert an actual load impedance…